# trying to delete my user but my code is not working

Tags: html, jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete a user but my ajax is not pickin up the ID of my selected user

My delete option lies in a table which is also generated through another ajax which after rendering look like this;

[image]

as I click on this option my delete modal opens up with my delete button, which looks like this

[image]

and on clicking this button I want the user to be deleted but it's not happening because this button is carrying or picking up the selected user ID, and I really don't know how to pass or hold the user ID behind this button so that it takes the user ID to my Stored procedure and deletes the user against their respective ID

my Stored Procedure is like this;

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveEmployee]
(
    @EmpID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE Employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
END
```

my delete method looks like this;

```
[Route("api/Employee/DeleteEmployee")]
    [HttpGet]
    public void DeleteEmployee(int ID)
    {
        int i;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("RemoveEmployee", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", ID);
            i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

this method is invoked by the following ajax but because my ajax is not picking up EmpID therefore my ajax call is not getting to my controller

the ajax looks like this;

```
$('#deleteEmp').click(function () {

    var data = new Object();
    data.EmpID = $('#empid').val(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        //data: { empid: EmpID },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#dvRoomsLoader").hide();
        },
        success: function () {

            alert("Employee Deleted Successfully...!");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occured while deleting Employee...!");
        }
    });
});
```

all the help is appreciated, your answers means a lot for me, keep supporting me
Thank you

Comment: `//data: { empid: EmpID },` - 1) it's commented...  2) it needs to match your Action parameter name, which is `ID` not `empid` - so change to `data: { ID: EmpID },`

Comment: Your Ajax function doesn't send the data

Comment: You aren't passing the data object to the ajax call, and even if the data object went through, your "DeleteEmployee" method is expecting an int ID, not an object with an EmpID property.

Answer (score 1):

try to fix  the action route

```
    Route("~/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/{ID}")]
    public void DeleteEmployee(int ID)
    {
      .....
   }
```

and  ajax

```
var empID = $('#empid').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/'+empID,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#dvRoomsLoader").hide();
        },
        success: function () {

            alert("Employee Deleted Successfully...!");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occured while deleting Employee...!");
        }
    });
});
```